# Are locally injective maps between topological manifolds topological immersions?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

Let $f:N \to M$ be a continuous function between general topological spaces. Let's assume that each point $p \in N$ has an open neighborhood $U$ such that $f|_U$ is an injection. Then $f|_U$ is a continuous bijection onto its image. However, $f|_U$ may not be a homeomorphism, so we cannot expect $f$ to be a topological immersion in general. If $N$ and $M$ are topological manifolds (Hausdorff, second countable, locally Euclidean), is $f$ a topological immersion? I know that, if $M$ is Hausdorff and we can take compact $V \subset U$ for each $p$ then $f|_V$ must be a homeomorphism onto its image, and so $f$ is a topological immersion. I conjectured that it should be for manifolds but failed to argue.

Comment: What is your definition of a topological immersion between topological spaces?

Comment: The definition is a continuous map for which each point of the domain has a neighborhood that is mapped onto its image homeomorphically.

Comment: Oh, I see. Then all what you need is that $N$ is locally compact and $M$ is Hausdorff. Now, note that manifolds are locally compact. Incidentally, there is no consensus on what a "neighborhood" means. Some people require it to be open, some do not.

Comment: I'm sorry. My question had a bug. My neighborhood is an open set. I edited the question to be clear. In locally compact spaces, each point has a neighborhood $V$ whose closure is compact. But how can I sure that $\bar{V}$ is contained in the open set $U$ in my question?

Comment: The most common definition of "locally compact" is that every point has a basis consisting of compact neighborhoods: Even open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ contains a compact neighborhood of $x$. This is what you want to use.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Thank you. Now I understand it.

Comment: Isn't the definition proposed in the second comment precisely that of a local homeomorphism?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Any response to Arrow please?

Comment: @SeleneAuckland Arrow is wrong, if you want a response.

Comment: @Arrow And what about you please?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Okay thanks. I may think about this more later.

Comment: @SeleneAuckland Just take a map from a singleton to the real line.

Comment: My comment was wrong. I asked a related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2583507/223002).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there are different notions of topological immersions:

1) A continuous locally injectve map between topological spaces. (Regretfully, one can find this in Spivak.)

2) A continuous map $f: X\to Y$ such that for every $x\in X$ there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $f|_U: U\to f(U)\subset Y$ is a homeomorphism.

3) Assuming that $X, Y$ are topological manifolds: A continuous map $f: X\to Y$ such that for every $x\in X$ there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ and a neighborhood $V$ of $y=f(x)$ and homeomorphisms $\phi: U\to R^m, \psi: V\to R^n$ such that the composition
$$
\psi\circ f \circ \phi^{-1}
$$ 
is an injective linear map $R^m\to R^n$. This you can find in the "[Manifold Atlas](http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Immersion)" and it is my favorite definition. Unlike 1 and 2, it allows one to prove some nontrivial theorems. An example which satisfies 2 but not 3 is a [wild sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_horned_sphere) in $R^3$. Maybe one should call maps satisfying 3 "tame topological immersions".

As for a relation between 1 and 2, they become equivalent if $X$ is locally compact and $Y$ is Hausdorff. Unfortunately, again, there are two closely related but inequivalent notions of local compactness. My favorite definition is that every point admits a basis consisting of compact neighborhoods, where neighborhoods are understood in the sense of Bourbaki. Another common definition of local compactness is that every points admits a compact neighborhood (or a relatively compact neighborhood if one requires neighborhoods to be open). The two definitions are equivalent if the space is assumed to be Hausdorff. See [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_compact_space) for further discussion. The bottom line is that if $X$ and $Y$ are Hausdorff and $X$ is locally compact (in either sense) then 1 is equivalent to 2.

Lastly, there is the notion of a [local homeomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_homeomorphism), which is a map $f: X\to Y$ such that every $x\in X, y=f(x)\in Y$ admit neighborhoods $U, V$ such that $f|_U: U\to V$ is a homeomorphism. This is, of course, strictly stronger than 2 or 3, but is equivalent to 3 if $X, Y$ are manifolds of the same dimension.